# Why does my .values() not work as intended

Tags: java

I've been trying to list loans out to the console using .values(), it works with the maps when listing out items or borrowers but for my loans, anyone know why?

```
public void listLoans(){
  System.out.println("Loans:");
  for (LoanTransaction t: loans.values()) {
      System.out.println(t);
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Accessors

```
public Map<Integer, Borrower>  getBorrowers() { return borrowers; }
public Map<Integer, Item>      getItems()     { return items; }
public List<LoanTransaction> getLoans()       { return loans; }
```

Example of Listing Items that works as intended

```
public void listItems() {
    System.out.println("Items:");
    for (Item i: items.values()) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
```

Comment: Just do: `for (LoanTransaction t: loans)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `values()` method for `List`. `Maps` need it to distinguish from the `keySet()` (and `entrySet()` which return key-value pairs). It's enough to use

```
for(LoanTransaction t: loans)
```

Generally speaking, anything that implements `Iterable` can be used as the right hand side of the for-each loop.

Comment: Thanks! Now just getting an issue where no results are being printed except for the initial "Loan:" println, not too sure why since there are loans contained within it

Comment: If there were loans in the list, something would be printed. Find out why there aren't loans in the list (maybe you have 2 lists).

Comment: Got it working, turns out I just didn't call in the function to read the data from the file haha, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`values()` available only on `map` as you said.

In case of `List`, those are the values it self. So just don't need the values

```
for (LoanTransaction t: loans.values())
```

should be

```
for (LoanTransaction t: loans)
```

Comment: Thanks! Now just getting an issue where no results are being printed except for the initial "Loan:" println, not too sure why since there are loans contained within it

Answer (score 0):

`values()` only works for maps, since maps are made of  pairs. `loans` is of type `List`, to get the elements in a list, you only need

```
for (LoanTransaction t: loans) {
      System.out.println(t);
  }
```